# Euler Lagrange equation with optimal quadratic function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, calculus-of-variations, numerical-optimization

Let $\lambda \in [0,1]$, $c \geq 0$. I want to find the quadratic functions $P: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $P(0)=0$ for which there exist $\bar{q}_P, \hat{q}_P \geq 0$ such that $P'(\bar{q}_P)+\bar{q}_P=1$ and $\frac{P(\hat{q}_P)}{\hat{q}_P}+\hat{q}_P=1$ that maximizes $$J(P):=\int_0^{q_{P}^*} {(P'(q)-c)(1+q-\lambda \frac{P(q)}{q}-(1-\lambda)P'(q))dq}$$ where $q_{P}^*:=\min \left\{{\bar{q}_P, \hat{q}_P}\right\}$.

My idea is to apply the Euler Lagrange equation to the function $$H(q,P(q),P'(q),P'''(q)):=L(q,P(q),P'(q))+\mu(q)P'''(q)$$ where $L(q,P(q),P'(q)):=(P'(q)-c)(1+q-\lambda \frac{P(q)}{q}-(1-\lambda)P'(q))$ and $\mu(q)$ is the Lagrange multiplicator associated to the restriction $P'''(q)=0$ for all $q \in [0,q_{P}^*]$, and then verify that the optimal $P$ satisfies the required conditions.

After apply the Euler Lagrange equation, I obtained the following differential equation:
$$-\mu'''-\frac{\partial}{{\partial q}}\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial P'}}+\frac{{\partial L}}{{\partial P}}=0$$.

By my problem is that the restriction $P'''=0$ and the previous differential equation allows different functional form choices for $\mu$ and $P$.

Comment: If you want quadratic functions only, then just plug in $P = a+ bq+cq^2$ and find $a, b, c$. Using E-L equation seems to be an overkill.

Comment: I think that I forgot something in my problem and is that $q^*$ depends on P. I tried to find $a, b$ and $c$ calculating the integral and characterizing the FOC, but the resulting FOC are quite complex.

Comment: I am pretty sure that $q^*_P$ do not depend smoothly on $P$. Indeed there are $P$ where there are infinitely many $\bar q_P$ or $\hat q_P$. I don't know what kinds of E-L equation would works for non-differentiable functionals.

Comment: But if $P$ is quadratic, there exists at most one $\hat{q_P}$ and at most one $\bar{q_P}$. But I think that since $q_P^*$ depend on $P$, the form to solve the problem is to write $P(q)=Aq^2+Bq$, and find optimal constants $A$ and $B$ sith $\hat{q_P} \leq \bar{q_P}$, and optimal constants with $\hat{q_P} \geq \bar{q_P}$, and then compare which gives the greater value for the integral of interest.